# How to set several keywords at once using google ads api

Tags: api, ads, keyword

I am trying to use google ads api to implement some actions in the google ads account. Now I want to add several keywords at once to an ad group. All the sample codes that I found are using only 1 keyword at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share the code what u have done so far?

Comment: [https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/basic_operations/add_keywords.py] I am using this code from github, but have no idea how to implement it on several keywords. Just for a single keyword, it worked. I am running it in command one using this code `python add_keywords.py  --customer_id=xxxx  --ad_group_id=xxxx  --keyword_text= keyword_example_text`.